Prevent Firefox Prompt Asking to Save 2FA Code
More and more sites require 2FA logins, which usually involves an intermediate page after username / password entry on which one has to enter a Time-based One-Time Password (TOTP). In many cases, Firefox seems to think that this field is a username or password for that site and asks whether it should save / update the credentials it saved. That is obviously nonsense as the TOTP code always changes. Is there a way to suppress that popup for the input in such fields?
I guess there can't be a very simple solution, since a pw and a TOTP input field are both <input type="password"> html tags. If there is currently no way, wouldn't it make sense that html gets a dedicated new field type?

You might find luck using a password manage that supports TOTP allowing you to associate the 2FA to the stored information so the password and the 2FA code are both filled out.

Firefox has had, for a long while, an option to never save passwords for a specific site: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1247704 . Does that not work?

@Ramhound, doesnt that defy the purpose of 2FA?
DrMoishePippik, I do want to save username and pw, just prevent the pointless prompt to save the TOTP

@Anonymous - How so? It’s still TOTP. You just let an extension handle generating the code.

I guess, but seems less secure. Anyway that's not the point of the question at all, is it
